# After row saved call back in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, jqgrid

I need to able to tap into an event after row has been updated, I use **inline editing**. There is a `beforeSend` event in `ajaxRowOptions` but no matching after.

How do I implement an after save callback?

Here is my grid:

```
 $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            jsonReader: common.jqgrid.jsonReader('Code'),
            editurl: common.getServerPath() + 'myAjax/updateSomething/',
            ajaxRowOptions: {
                beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
                   //something here
                 }
                }
            }, 

            mtype: 'POST',
            pager: '#myPager',
            colNames: ['Method', 'Type', 'Package', 'Disc %'],
            colModel: [
               {
                    name: 'Code',
                    index: 'Code',
                    width: 25,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'MethodType',
                    index: 'MethodType',
                    width: 10,
                    sortable: false,
                    align: 'center'
                },
                {
                    name: 'ProfNo',
                    index: 'ProfNo',
                    width: 15,
                    sortable: false,
                    align: 'center'
                },

                   {
                    name: 'Discount',
                    index: 'Discount',
                    width: 15,
                    sortable: false,
                    edittype: 'text',
                    align: 'right',
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: {
                        number: false,
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func: validateDiscount                     
                    }
                }],

            scroll: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            altRows: true,
            altclass: 'gridAltRowClass',
            height: 330, 
            scrollOffset: 0,
            width: 770, 
            rowNum: 500,
            footerrow: true,
            userDataOnFooter: true
});
```

and

```
    validateDiscount: function (value) {

    if (isNaN(value)) {
        return [false, 'Discount must be a number.'];
    }
    else {
        var numValue = parseFloat(Number(value).toFixed(2));

        if (numValue >= 100.00) {
            return [false, 'is not a valid value. Discount must be a number less than 100.'];
        }
    }

    return [true, ''];
},
```

Comment: I recommend you to read the docs. There is such event - you need just to find it - five minutes to find it against one day of waiting

Comment: It depend which version of jqGrid you use and from where you read the documentation. Can you please, give answer of these questions?

Comment: I am looking [at this doc](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing), some of those sound like good post-save events.